# Mosby 3 MVP - presenter is always recreated when go back to the fragment in the back stack

Tags: android, mvp, mosby

When we do `popBackStack` and return to the previous fragment in the back stack, the bundle in the method `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle bundle)` is always null due to the fact that `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` wasn't called before. So, when we go back, bundle is null and a presenter (and view state) is created again. How in this case we can reuse presenter and view state (and not recreate it)?

You can see a dummy example below. There is a fragment with 2 buttons. One button opens a new Fragment and another button goes to the previous one. When you go back, presenter and view states are recreated. That's not I need, but I described above why it's happenning according to the code in the library.
Is there a way to ensure that we reuse presenter and view state when we go back?

```
public class FirstFragment extends MvpViewStateFragment<FirstFragmentView, FirstFragmentPresenter, FirstFragmentViewState> {

public static final String TAG = "TAG";

private Button moveToAnotherFragmentButton;
private Button moveBackButton;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
    moveToAnotherFragmentButton = (Button) rootFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.first_fragment_go_to_another_fragment_button);
    moveBackButton = (Button) rootFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.first_fragment_back_button);
    return rootFragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    moveToAnotherFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(ignored -> addToStack(FirstFragment.class));
    moveBackButton.setOnClickListener(ignored -> getFragmentManager().popBackStack());
}

@Override
@NonNull
public FirstFragmentPresenter createPresenter() {
    Log.e(TAG, "createPresenter");
    return new FirstFragmentPresenter();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public FirstFragmentViewState createViewState() {
    Log.e(TAG, "createViewState");
    return new FirstFragmentViewState();
}

@Override
public void onNewViewStateInstance() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onNewViewStateInstance");
}

private void addToStack(@NonNull final Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.isDestroyed()) {
        throw new UnexpectedException("FragmentManager is destroyed");
    }

    final Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getContext(), fragmentClass.getName());

    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_container, fragment, null)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
}
```

Comment: put your code here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I added the small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator of this library answered this question [here](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/265). The short answer: "this behavior was not intended".